# MVC 5 web application with Oracle 11g and Entity Framework without Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

my company is using the old **Oracle.DataAccess** and **Oracle 11g (release 2)** on many servers with many apps, so I can't update the driver.
Now I have to create a web app, and i'd like to use EF's code first.
The problem is that it works only with the newest ManagedDataAccess, and I can't use it.

Is there any way I can map EF with the oldest driver?

Answer (score 0):

ODP.NET Managed Driver is only a single DLL (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll). There is nothing to install, just put a copy of this DLL to your application directory, that's it. Thus you do not affect any other Oracle installation.

Comment: I installed that via NuGet but I'm not able to select those drivers in the EF's connection string, they are not even listed as data providers. I think that's cause I should install ODTwithODAC, which is what I want to avoid because I can't install those on the server

Comment: Install it from here, it is easier: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog/28695779#28695779

Comment: The fact is if I install that on my machine I will have to install it on the server also, and I can't do that 'cause it would mess up the other applications using the old driver

Comment: No, that's not true. You don't have to *install* anything on the server. Just copy the DLL.

Comment: From the docs: 
_Execute install_odpm.bat to install and configure Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver._ which will create a _managed_ folder containing the driver on the oracle base, causing the other applications to break.
Also, I am using **Oracle 11.2 Release 2 32bit**

Comment: Try it out! Take a PC without any Oracle installation at all and copy Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll to your application folder. The application should run without any problem - that is the purpose of ODP.NET Managed Driver!

Comment: I'll try, thanks.
I hope the managed driver will show up by itself in the list when using EF