# ODP.NET driver does not show up in Data Source dialog (no Client)

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, entity-framework, nuget

I installed Oracle Data Provider for .NET via NuGet as explained in the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/NuGet/index.html). Now, the tutorial expressly states at stage 8 that:

> Note: You will see that ODP.NET and Entity Framework configuration
>   information has been added to the project. Managed ODP.NET does not
>   require any Oracle Client installation.

Indeed, I did not install the Oracle Client. However, when I try to use the Entity Data Model Wizard in VS2013 or VS2015 the Managed Driver does not show up - see [VS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnebL.jpg).

1. How do I get the Wizard to show the Managed Driver? Must I install ODTwithODAC or is there a way to avoid it?
2. Is it possible to use Entity Framework ("EF Designer from Database") without using the Wizard?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28695779/3027266