# VS2017 doesn't see Oracle drivers?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I just recently installed VS2017 on my machine. Today I went to start a new MVC site and wanted to add a DataContext to our Oracle server. The first thing I did was go to NuGet Manager and added the Oracle Managed Drivers and then Entity Framework for Oracle and all that looked to install correctly. I then went to Add | New Item | Data | Entity Data Model | Code First from DB.

From there where it asks which database you want to connect to I only have Microsoft drivers. If I try to add a new connection, again no Oracle drivers are listed in the driver type.

I then closed the project and opened in up in VS2015. Went to add a new Data Model and it all worked as expected. Oracle drivers were available and I was able to make an Entity for my tables.

Is there something I need to install or add to my VS2017 in order to get it to see my Oracle drivers and make a connection to Oracle?

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog/28695779#28695779

Answer (score 0):

You need ODP.NET. It is in Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017, but last version is anvalible for vs2015 https://community.oracle.com/thread/4024914