# How to connect oracle database with ASP.NET(C#) MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm newbie c#.net mvc. I'm want to using asp.net mvc to connect with oracle database.

First, I'm downloaded OracleManagedDataAccess and OracleManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework by nuget.

Second, I'm try to add new item at model folder. Then select ADO.NET Entity Data Model and click new connection. I can't found oracle database for select. Just find Microsoft SQL Server only.

Anyone could you help me please.

[image]

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog/28695779#28695779

Comment: I can't found /odp.net.managed.