# Connecting VS 2017 to Oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, odac

I'm trying to connect an Oracle database from my VS 2017. I installed ODAC for VS 2017 19.3.1.0.0 to do that.

Then when I open VS and install the `Oracle.ManagedDataAcces` package, and then click on "Add connection", I can't find the new `ODP.NET MANAGED DRIVER`.

Any help please?

Thank you !

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog/28695779#28695779

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managed ODP.NET driver does not show up in Data Source dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694919/managed-odp-net-driver-does-not-show-up-in-data-source-dialog)